# Cells not displaying in SearchBar -Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, searchbar

I'm fairly new to Xcode and am having trouble getting my head around why the table view data isn't displaying in the searchbar. Basically trying to return fetched results to a searchbar. Thanks in advance!

```
    #import "DeviceViewController.h"
#import "DeviceDetailViewController.h"
@interface DeviceViewController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *devices;
@end

@implementation DeviceViewController
{
    NSArray *recipes;
    NSArray *searchResults;
}
@synthesize recipe;
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    //label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-thin" size:28];
    //label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    label.text = @"TapNotes";
    [label sizeToFit];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return self.devices.count;
    }
    //return self.devices.count;
    }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"name"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device valueForKey:@"version"]]];
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        recipe = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

   // cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.image];

    return cell;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateDevice"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        DeviceDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.device = selectedDevice;
    }
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 55;
}
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: show your error log...? Undeclared identifier of what.......?

Comment: I just did a clean which seemed to fix the error. But now when I search in the search bar, the data from my table view is not displaying. arg

Comment: Hey man? What you got in debugging area as error? Just post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things don't look right here.

1. Why are you not using a `NSFetchedResultsConteroller`?
2. What is the connection between `recipes` and `devices` arrays
3. **You are not setting the recipes array** (you filter it on `filterContentForSearchText:`)
4. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` always set data for cell by the `devices` array
5. You have a lot of "dead" code

It looks like you took this code from an example and modified it, but only half way.

Comment: Thanks Dan! You are correct. I was using a website called AppCoda on "How to implement search bar in iOS 7". Most of the code is correct, the dead zone seems to be in the cellForRowAtIndexPath where the code doesn't seem to be responding and also the NSArray. Where should I go from here? Thanks

Comment: Start by removing the `recipes` variable and correct errors that appear by this modification. that should get you started. next fix your `cellForRow...` to first get the model you need from the proper array (search or devices) and only then setup the cell ...

Comment: I fixed those things & I works now. This means the world to me! Cheers brah:3